# DataGrid will not display the dataset/recordset

Tags: database, vb.net, datagridview

I consider myself a very patient guy with a whole lot of determination to get things working within say, a program i'm working on. However, I feel that I am only wasting precious time that I could be using to actually gain knowledge in something rather than hitting my head against a wall accomplishing nothing. SO.. I'm going to pretend the 11 hours I spent today trying to fix this problem was not wasted, as long as im able to fix it.
I'm new to databases and am working on a database program. It was written in vb6 and im trying to rewrite it in vb.net. I've completely stripped the program down from all the unneeded fancy addons and now just have the needed code to run it. The program retreives the records, but does not populate these records onto a datagrid. And yes, I did try to find help on other posts and google searches but I was unable to get any of the solutions to work for me.

form1

```
Imports ADS_SQL_TEST_VBNET
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
Module1.Main()
End Sub

Public Sub cmdSQLBound_Click()
sWhichDataType = "SQL"
Call SetGridSize("SQL Table Bound.")
End Sub

Public Sub optYes01ph_Click()
BuildTable()         'sets sFields and sQuery
cmdSQLBound_Click()
End Sub

End Class
```

module1

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports ADS_SQL_TEST_VBNET.Form1
Imports ADS_SQL_TEST_VBNET.Class1

Public Module Module1

Public rs As ADODB.Recordset
Public db As ADODB.Connection

Public dgvDataGrid As DataGridView
Public DataGridRef As New DataGridView
Public sWhichDataType, sSource, sTable, sFields, sQuery, sFilter, sOrderBy, sSelectedIndex, sStoreId    
Public lblCount As Object
Public Ctrl1, Ctrl2, Freq, Overhead As Decimal
Public l, x As Integer
Public A, I As Long


Public Sub Main()

  Form1.optYes01ph_Click()

End Sub


Public Sub BuildTable()
    If sTable = "yes01ph" Or sTable = "" Then
        sTable = "yes01ph"
        sFields = "store_id,control_no,first_name,last_name,company,address,city,State,zip,phone,total,stat_code,Year,make_id,model_id,engine_id,contact,phone1,phone2,phone3,phone4,invoice_no,ready_proc,summary,note"
        sOrderBy = "control_no"
    Else
        sFields = "store_id,ml_id,first_name,last_name,company,address,city,state,zip,phone,last_upd,address2,phone2,ref_count,comments,fobs_key,quest,lockedby,rmte_stat,serv_upd,serv_id,psm_use,psm_points"
        sOrderBy = "ml_id"
    End If
    BuildFilter()
End Sub

Public Sub BuildFilter()
    sFilter = " AND control_no > 1 AND control_no < 500000"
    BuildQuery()
End Sub

Public Sub BuildQuery()

    sQuery = "SELECT " & sFields & " FROM " & sTable & " WHERE Store_ID Like 'XXX' " & sFilter & " Order By " & sOrderBy
    sQuery = Replace(sQuery, "'XXX'", "'" & Trim(UCase("250")) & "'")
End Sub



Public Sub SetGridSize(ByVal sMessage As String)

    Dim lblTableType As String
    lblTableType = "  " & sMessage
    Form1.dgvDataGrid.Text = "Data populated using: " & UCase(sMessage)

    DataGridRef.ColumnCount = 99
    DataGridRef.RowCount = 1

    DataSetRef.LoadDataBound()
End Sub
End Module
```

Class1

```
Public Class Class1

Public Sub LoadDataBound()

rs = GetData()
If Not rs.EOF Then
    dgvDataGrid.DataSource = rs '     Bind the Datagrid to the recordset
    dgvDataGrid.Refresh()
Else
    MsgBox("No Records Found in DataGrid!")
End If
End Sub

Public Function GetData() As ADODB.Recordset
sWhichDataType = UCase(Trim(sWhichDataType))

sSource = "development"
GetData = OpenSQL()
End Function

Public Function OpenSQL() As ADODB.Recordset
db = New ADODB.Connection : rs = New ADODB.Recordset ' Initialize Connection object &    RecordSet object

With db
    .CursorLocation = ADODB.CursorLocationEnum.adUseClient
    .Mode = ADODB.ConnectModeEnum.adModeReadWrite
    .ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=pacesql;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=speedwrench;Data Source=" & sSource
    .Open() ' "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=development", "sa", "pacesql", -1
End With

OpenSQL = db.Execute(sQuery)
End Function

End Class
```

I think the problem lies within the LoadDataBound() Sub routine, but I can't say for sure since I was unable to fix this myself. Thank you so much to whoever takes the time to read all of this and sorry if it's currently sloppy and is loaded with un-used methods or vars... I've completely BUTCHERED this thing trying to get it to work.

Comment: I think you are using ADO instead of ADO.NET. Try binding a Datatable instead of a Recordset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is you are using ADO rather than ADO.NET.

I don't have time to work out your code, but maybe you should start with something that works. This should pull out some data from your database and fill the datagridview. You'll need to change the connection string and table/fieldnames etc of course:

```
  Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Dim strCnn As String = "Data Source=sqlservername;Timeout=10;Database=databasename;Trusted_Connection=no;User ID=userid;Password=password;"
    Using cnn As New SqlConnection(strCnn)
      cnn.Open()
      Dim strSql As String = "SELECT * FROM Tablename"
      Dim dtb As New DataTable
      Using dad As New SqlDataAdapter(strSql, cnn)
        dad.Fill(dtb)
      End Using
      'now hide all the columns except the ones we want to show'
      dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = False 'dgv is the name of the datagridview'
      Dim intColIndex As Integer
      intColIndex = dgv.Columns.Add("Field1", "Field 1") 'aliases'
      dgv.Columns(intColIndex).DataPropertyName = "F1" 'column name in database'
      intColIndex = dgv.Columns.Add("Field3", "Field 3") 'aliases'
      dgv.Columns(intColIndex).DataPropertyName = "F3" 'column name in database'
      'now bind'
      dgv.DataSource = dtb
    End Using
  End Sub
```

Oh, you'll need

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
```

at the top of the source code for the form.